# Reading registers from ACS71020 over SPI

Tags: spi, current-sensing, allegro

I'm trying to read registers from current-sensing chip ACS71020 connected over SPI.

This is how I initialize the SPI:

```
bc_spi_init(BC_SPI_SPEED_1_MHZ, BC_SPI_MODE_0);
```

The code for reading is such:

```
    uint8_t tx_buffer[2]= {0x1E | 0x80 };  // Register to read with highest bit set to 1 
    uint8_t rx_buffer[4] = {0x01, 0x02,0x03, 0x04};        

    if(bc_spi_is_ready())
    { 
        bc_spi_transfer(tx_buffer, NULL, 0);
        bc_spi_transfer(NULL, rx_buffer, sizeof(rx_buffer));
        bc_log_info("rx_buffer1:%d", rx_buffer[0]);  
        bc_log_info("rx_buffer2:%d", rx_buffer[1]);  
        bc_log_info("rx_buffer3:%d", rx_buffer[2]);  
        bc_log_info("rx_buffer4:%d", rx_buffer[3]);  
    }
```

`
Is it correct to set the highest bit of the register to 1 when reading? That is how I understand the spec.

Also no matter what register I read, I always get the same four values back. Is there something I'm missing?

I'm using the Big Clown (STM32L083CZ)
https://developers.hardwario.com/hardware/about-core-module

Comment: Which MCU are you using?

Comment: I'm using the Big Clown (STM32L083CZ) 
https://developers.hardwario.com/hardware/about-core-module

Comment: That's what I suspected. I believe that STM32 SPI uses MSB first shift order by default, and the Big Clown API doesn't appear to have an option for changing it.

Answer (score 0):

The ACS71020 expects SPI data MSB first, with the slave address bits 6:0 sent first followed by the read/write bit. Therefore the value should be `{(0x1e << 1) | 0x01}`

If your SPI port has configurable bit shift order then it should also be set for MSB first (this may be the default).